# How to find the rows from a table which has exactly two 'n' s in the employee name?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I want to find all the employees whose names have exactly two n's in their name. How can this be done?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this should be enough:

```
select * from employee_table where Length(lastname) - length(replace(lastname, 'n','')) = 2
```

be aware that may cause a full table scan :-)